# Can I use Google Drive's editor interface embed in a website?

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to use google drive to store the files, but allow the users of my website to be able to edit them transparently, so that they don't have to go to google drive's website.

Is this possible with the current API? Thus far I have only seen how to create an app for them to install in google drive, or doing something like DrEdit (https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/), which parses the files to JSON and uses the ACE editor, which is definitely not what I want.

**EDIT:**

I believe it is not possible to do this with Google Drive, I've decided to go with Zoho Docs instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. The biggest consideration is how much formatting you want to support. Eg. if it's plain text, it's very simple. If you want to support character or layout formatting, it becomes more complex.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe its possible to embed the editor (or even embed a preview!) using an iframe, because if you look at how the google docs page loads, it first redirects you to the login page, and that automatically logs you in if you are already logged in, and redirects you back to the docs editor.

This means that the iframe would have to at least pass through the login page, even if the user doesn't need to enter anything. However, google's login page has the x-frame-option header set to SAMEORIGIN (or deny?), and thus, the browser refuses to display it, and thus you can't actually get logged in!

The only way I've found to enable just preview embedding (not editing), is to publish the document first (via the File->publish to web menu item).